# How to monitor the available bandwith without impacting an already running stream?

Tags: networking, packages, switches, gstreamer

I have a RTP stream called 'X1' running from a Pi to a Linux PC. At the same time I want to create more streams, for example X2, X3 e.t.c...

Depending on the available bandwidth, I would like to know if there is a tool, or a Python script if possible, that monitors the available bandwidth without impacting the X1 stream in real time.

Comment: Tools that reports bandwidth will not require any, they get the information from [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) (look in `/proc/net/dev`).  Put another way, **there are no such tools that would impact "an already running stream"**, so you can use anything you find.

Comment: @goldilocks if I'm not wrong '/proc/net/dev' will only show how many packages the system is sending but not the amount you can actually send for you to understand the bandwith you can use, right?

Comment: There's no such statistic as  "bandwidth available" except as an abstraction derived from what is being is being used and what you know the interface's potential is in theory (which is probably much more than it is in practice at any given moment).  It's even more abstract since "what's being used" can really only refer to what was just used in a given timeframe.  Assuming that number is stable though, it provides a clue.

Comment: E.g., if there is no activity on the ethernet jack, you can assume at most there's 100 Mbps available.  However, there is no way for the system to tell how realistic that is as it depends upon external factors (the network, the remote parties).